# Не работает Google Map в приложении

Tags: android, c#, xamarin, monodroid

Добрый день.

Пишу приложение для Android (Xamarin - C#)

Вопрос состоит в том, что при компиляции напрямую - карта в приложении работает, а когда залил в Google Play, карта не работает.

Высвечивается логотип Google и все.

`SHA-1` код и ключ в приложении правильны.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: в неправильном ключе, например. С чего вы взяли, что ключ правильный?

Comment: с того , что я посмотрел ключ в манифесте и в консоле разработчика, он один и тот же @metalurgus

Comment: и мне кажется, если бы он был неправильным, при скомпилированном напрямую на девайс проекте карта бы тоже не работала, не так ли? @metalurgus

Comment: Обычно *при скомпилированном напрямую на девайс проекте* заливается `debug` конфигурация, которую нужно компилировать с `debug` ключем. А в маркет заливается другая конфигурация, в которой должен быть зашит не `debug` ключ

Comment: я заливать пробовал с параметром Release  и работало тоже.

API key насколько я понял прописывается в манифесте и не меняется

При выгрузке в маркет прописывается сверху только сертификат насколько я понимаю @metalurgus